# not getting ajax value into a php variable?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

My Script is:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".states").on('click','option',function(){

        var selValue = $("select[id='stateId'] option:selected").val();

            $.post('<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/ajax.php', 'val=' + selValue, function (response) {

                $variable = response;
                //alert("Variable value is: "+$variable);

            }); 

    });

});
```

Select Events Location

            
            

            
                
                    Select Country
                
            
            
                
                    Select State
                
            
            
                
                    Select City

```
    <div class="col-sm-9">


        <?php 
         $a2 = $variable;
         print_r($a); die;
        $args = array(
            'meta_key' => 'state',
            'meta_value' => $a2,
            'post_type' => 'event',
            'posts_per_page' => -1
        );
        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

        // The Loop
        if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
            echo '<ul>';
            while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
                $the_query->the_post();
                echo '<li><h2>' . get_the_title() . '</h2></li><br>';
            }
            echo '</ul>';
        } else {
            echo 'no posts found';
        }
        /* Restore original Post Data */
        wp_reset_postdata();

        //echo do_shortcode('[qem]'); ?>        

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Change `'val=' + selValue` to { val : selValue }

Comment: actually I want to filter post according to state. And getting state value via ajax post(). I need to get it into a php variable. Or pass this value into array value  "'meta_value' => $a2".

Comment: first you need to change what i suggest, and than the variable populated by it self. But if it is a PHP variable the you can't .

Comment: I have change it sir. and working also

Comment: You need to write that value into any `div` or other tags...

Comment: I have write in <h1><?php echo $_GET[$variable]; ?></h1> for testing. but nothing is comming.

Comment: my ajax.php file code is <?php
  
  
   $value = $_POST['val'];
   echo $value;

?>

Comment: Checkout my answer and let me know it works for you or not?

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

You need to send value like `{ val : selValue }`, and in `ajax.php` you have to store value as `$_POST` as you pass it ike `$.post`, and must return the response.

After returning the response it is set to the `H1` tags text.

**Ajax:**

```
$.post('<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/ajax.php', { val : selValue }, function (response) {
    variable = response;
});
```

**PHP**

```
$variable = "<script>document.write(variable);</script>";
```

You can try this, let me know what happen.

Comment: yes sir getting selected value in h1. But how can i pass it into $args = array(
    'meta_key' => 'state',
    'meta_value' => $a2,
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
   ); at place of "$a2 "

Comment: **_You cann't do this job as you think the way._**

Comment: but you can use a form value which will be submitted so you can get it in that array.

Comment: can you please give some more idea on it because i am new in development. how to use form in it

Comment: sir, without submit button we can get this value into a variable on same page.

Comment: How?? Please share with me now.

Comment: Is this possible we can submit form without button.

Comment: For PHP you can't.

Comment: is this possible that submit this form with jquery and get value into a variable

Comment: You can try this: `$variable = "<script>document.write(variable);</script>";`

Comment: [object HTMLHeadingElement] This is comming

Comment: Thank you sir :) and sorry to late reply:(

Comment: if you helped and think this answer correct than you need to Mark this as helpful.